How to inference a tflite model in flutter?
I am trying to create a recommendation machine learning model, but when I deploy it to flutter, I cannot process my input.
Here is my code in flutter to inference the model:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';

class RecommendationModel {
  late final Interpreter _recommendationInterpreter;

  RecommendationModel({
    String recommendationModelPath = "assets/user_retrieval.tflite",
  }) {
    _loadModel(recommendationModelPath);
  }

  Future<void> _loadModel(String recommendationModelPath) async {
    _recommendationInterpreter =
        await Interpreter.fromAsset(recommendationModelPath);
    print("Recommendation model loaded");
  }

  Future<void> testUserRetrievalModel(String userId) async {
    try {
      // Convert the user ID to a byte array
      var userIdBytes = utf8.encode(userId);
      var input = Uint8List.fromList(
          userIdBytes); // Convert string to list of ASCII code units

// Prepare the output tensor (adjust this shape based on your model's expected output)
      var output = List.filled(10, 1).reshape([1, 10]);

// Run inference
      _recommendationInterpreter.run(input, output);

// Access the second output
      var secondOutput = output[0][1];
      print('Second output: $secondOutput');

      // Convert output tensor to a list of recipe IDs (or scores) and print them
      List<int> recommendations = output[0].cast<int>().toList();
      print("Recommended recipe IDs: $recommendations");
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error during prediction: $e');
    }
  }

  void dispose() {
    _recommendationInterpreter.close();
  }
}


I'm thinking that my tflite model perhaps only accepts a numpy string array. If so how can I prepare format that in dart?
I tried first to run inference in python and I got what I expected with the following code:
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Load the TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="/content/drive/MyDrive/Models/user_retrieval.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
print(output_details)

# Test the model 
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
# Providing a string input as per the model's expectation
input_data = np.array(["42"], dtype=np.string_)  # Assuming user IDs are strings
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])
print(output_data)

this have a output:
[{'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall_1:0', 'index': 10,
 'shape': array([ 1, 10], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([-1, 10], dtype=int32), 
'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0),
'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 
'quantized_dimension': 0},
 'sparsity_parameters': {}}, {'name':'StatefulPartitionedCall_1:1', 'index': 12, 
'shape': array([ 1, 10], dtype=int32), 'shape_signature': array([-1, 10], dtype=int32), 
'dtype': <class 'numpy.int32'>, 
'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 
'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
[[ 9632  3237   269  5371 10433  7573   378  7341 12037  8441]]

I'm expecting that this accepts numpy arrays? not a direct string specially in flutter, but in save model format, it accepts a raw string type.
